# check which type of file selected by user in c# in uwp

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, uwp, uwp-xaml

User can select multiple types of files- .txt or .pdf
Based on the selected file type different actions are taken.
How to check which type of file selected by the user in c#

Answer (score 0):

If you have the path to the file you can check by using Path.GetExtension() and create a switch between supported types.

See: 
[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In UWP if you want to get the extension of a file that user selects, Since this is a `StorageFile`, You can directly use [`FileType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_FileType)` on Storage File.